# Change default file permissions on debian

Tags: permissions, debian, chmod

I've setup a Debian cloud server. I installed apache, php and then vsftpd. I created users and set permission etc.

When I upload a file, its default permissions are 600 and I can't view the file unless I manually change it to 774 or 775.

So, I'd like to change **the default** permissions of **all files that I upload** to /var/www/ to **754**.

I know that `chmod -R 754 /var/www` makes all files within that directory to 774 but it doesn't change the default permissions of all new files that are uploaded.

My user is 'joe' for demo purpose since I'm learning, so I even tried `chown -R joe /var/www` but that didn't change the default permissions either.

How do I change it default permissions from 600 to 774? In which file should I write and what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `umask`. More info here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html

Comment: Thank you. I should mention that I checked in unmask and I changed all unmask with no positive results

Comment: Are you sure you got the correct syntax? It's `umask` not `uNmask`

Comment: Oops sorry. Well I never wrote that word. I just changed the number ever time

Comment: after I perform all this tasks what do I have to restart? Apache, vsftpd or nothing?

Answer (score 1):

You must change the umask of the user(s) writing to the directory. And BTW do NOT set execute permissions when they are not needed.

A umask is a negative mask of permissions which should be applied. By default, all files would be created with 666 and all directories with 777. With a umask of 002, which seems to be what you want, these become 664 and 775.

Now, how to set the umask depends on the program which actually writes the file, and whether this setting is available in its configuration file.

Another, less known way, would be to set POSIX ACLs to the upload directory: for this, you can use `setfacl` with the `-d` option on `/var/www` (provided your OS, and filesystem, support it both).

Comment: Hi and thank you. I think this is what I am looking for. I checked previously about unmask and I edited the file: /etc/profile and /etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf but nothing changed. Is there any other files I should check in?

Comment: See the addendum: you may try `setfacl`.

Comment: I also changed: /etc/login.defs. Sorry what is addendum? And after I perform all this tasks what do I have to restart? Apache, vsftpd or nothing?

Comment: I meant the post edit. Actually, you want ACLs for your use case.

Comment: So I type setfacl -d /var/www/ ? Sorry sir, its seriously my first day with servers. So any key words are very hard for me at the moment. Thanks

Comment: Look at the man page of `setfacl`. See here for examples: http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_setfacl.htm

Comment: Okay I think this is what I am looking for. I've installed ACL on my server and tried to perform setfacl -d /var/www/ . I am missing the {-m,-x} though. Is that the permission number or the umask number?

Comment: I would assume it would be something like setfacl -d 775 /var/www ?

Comment: No, you didn't read the manpage... Try `setfacl -dm g::rwx /var/www`.

Comment: Thank you. I get this error: /var/www: Operation not supported

Comment: According to this: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/setfacl-operation-not-supported-641085/, I have to set defaults

Comment: It means the underlying filesystem does not support ACLs... Too bad, you'll have to use umasks ;)

Comment: You know with umask's. When I change the default values, what do I have to restart afterwards so that it takes effect? It seems nothing changes

Answer (score 1):

One of your comments suggests you are uploading the files through proftpd. If this is the case, then your question is really specific to that piece of software. The answer is not to go modifying /etc/profile, as that is going to change the default umask for all users that use Bourne Shell or similar (i.e. Bash). Furthermore, a user must actually log into the shell for /etc/profile to be read, and on a properly configured system, the user your daemon is running as does not actually log in. Check http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Umask.html for information specific to proftpd and umasks.